# Simple Foreign Key Relation with Knex and Bookshelf.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm attempting what should be a simple example of foreign key relations. `regions` and `subregions` are separate tables. There is a 1:Many relationship between `regions:subregions`, where the column `region_fk` on table `subregions` is mapped to an `id` from table `regions`. Each table also has a `name` column. The goal is to return the name of the region and the names of all subregions.

The query works fine without the `{withRelated: ...}` parameter, so something must be amiss with the connection between the models.

**knex migration**

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable("regions", function(table) {
      table.integer("id").primary();
      table.string("name");
    }),

    knex.schema.createTable("subregions", function(table) {
      table.integer("id").primary();
      table.string("name");
      table
        .integer("region_fk")
        .references("id")
        .inTable("regions");
    }),
  ])
}
```

**bookshelf.config.js**

```
var knex = require("knex")(require("./knexfile.js").development);
var bookshelf = require("bookshelf")(knex);
bookshelf.plugin("registry");
module.exports = bookshelf;
```

**bookshelf models**

```
// Region
const bookshelf = require("../bookshelf.config");

const Region = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: "regions",

  subregions: function() {
    return this.hasMany("Subregion", "region_fk");
  },
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model("Region", Region);

// Subregion
const bookshelf = require("../bookshelf.config");
const Subregion = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: "subregions",

  region: function() {
    return this.belongsTo("Region", "region_fk");
  },
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model("Subregion", Subregion);
```

**Query**

```
const Region = require("../../models/region");

export const getRegionWithId = (req, res) => {
  new Region()
    .where("id", req.params.id)
    .fetch({ withRelated: ["subregions"], require: true })
    .then(region => {
      res.status(200).json(region);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(404).json(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Appears to be some issue with the `registry` plugin. Modifying the model from `return this.hasMany("Subregion", "region_fk");` to `return this.hasMany(Subregion, "region_fk");` with the appropriate import resolved the issue. No official answer yet because I don't understand why the first method fails.

Comment: This could be a bug. Can you provide a reproducible test case and file a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues)?

Comment: Oh, and just a small note. I'm not sure how that `.references("id").inTable("regions");` even works, considering there's a chance that the `regions` table isn't created when that call is made given the parallel nature of `Promise.all`. You should chain those `createTable()` calls instead for guaranteed reliability.